# Select list opção selecionada com AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Estou implementando um *select list* que tem como *options* os estados brasileiros.

Gostaria de retornar o valor selecionado de acordo com o retorno de um web service. Por exemplo, se o serviço retornar `RJ` então `RJ` deve ser a *option selected*.

Isso é muito simples de implementar com Javascript e Jquery, mas nunca fiz em Angular. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

```
 <select id="txtUf" class="customSel">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AP">AP</option>
    <option value="AM">AM</option> 
    ...
 </select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<select id="txtUf" class="customSel" ng-model="Dados.uf">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Selecione</option>
    <option value="AC">AC</option>
    <option value="AL">AL</option>
    <option value="AP">AP</option>
    <option value="AM">AM</option> ...  
</select>
```

A solução seria incluir o `ng-model`, "dados.uf" é o valor da sigla do estado, lembrando que o valor da Dados.uf deve ser igual ao valor do value da option.

Comment: It worked! Obrigado.